# R filtering for strings across several columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of several rows of characters. For reasons I can't get into here, I need to leave these columns as character columns, but need to filter out rows containing letters.

In short, something like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | B |
| 5 | 6 | 7 |

Without converting the columns into numeric columns, I need to filter out the first two rows because they contain text characters.

I tried the following but no luck:

```
df %>%
filter(str_detect(c(A:C), "[AZ]") != "[AZ]")
```

Comment: Do you mean `"[A-Z]"`? `"[AZ]"` would just match on the characters "A" or "Z". Aside from that, it's unclear what you expect that syntax to do...`str_detect` returns a logical value, but you're comparing it with the string `"[AZ]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `stringr` and `str_detect` you can try:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(across(A:C, ~!str_detect(., "[A-Z]")))
```

Or to `filter` based on all columns in the data.frame:

```
df %>% 
  filter(across(everything(), ~!str_detect(., "[A-Z]")))
```

**Edit**: As mentioned in the comments, starting with dplyr v. 1.0.4, you can use the new functions `if_any` or `if_all` with `filter`. For example:

```
df %>%
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~!str_detect(., "[A-Z]")))
```

**Output**

```
  A B C
1 5 6 7
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! Both options worked, but the first works for my specific problem since I only want to filter certain columns.

Comment: `across` can't be used with `filter` in newer `dplyr` versions. You can just replace `across` with `if_any` though to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(if_all(.fns = function(x) as.numeric(x)))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
    A     B     C    
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1   5     6     7
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R you might do `df[complete.cases(sapply(df, match, 0:9)),]`